# check arrival date and departure are within range mysql

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have following table :

```
id      travelStart travelExpires
1       2012-11-12  2013-01-31
1       2012-11-12  2013-01-31
```

and following are my arrival and departure dates:

```
arrival date: 2012-12-28
departure date   : 2012-12-30
```

I want to check that arrival and departure date in between travelStart and travelEnd date. How to write mysql query for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer has as simplest solution the `BETWEEN` operator in MySQL. How it works:

```
SELECT * from YourTable WHERE ( :arrivalDate BETWEEN travelStart AND travelExpires) AND ( :departureDate BETWEEN travelStart AND travelExpires )
```

You'll obviously need to bind the `:arrivalDate` and `:departureDate` parameters.

Comment: `$result = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE CURDATE() between bookingStart and bookingExpires AND (( $travelStart BETWEEN travelStart AND travelExpires) AND ( $travelEnd BETWEEN travelStart AND travelExpires )", array($couponcode));`

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket. AND travelExpires ))

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select * from table where (arrival_date<=travelStart AND arrival_date<=travelExpires) AND (departure_date>=travelStart AND departure_date<=travelExpires)
```